# How add query parameters correctly

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on API request. I would like to modify name of product using id  I use static URL + `$id`.
How can I add all stuff in single URL?

```
static const String MODIFY_BOX = MAIN_API_URL + "auth/modify-box";
```

and this is the method:

```
 Future<String> modifyBox(String name, int id) async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String token = localStorage.getString('access_token');
    await checkInternet();
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
    };
    Map<String, dynamic> body = {
      'boxName': name,
    };
    print(body);
    inspect(body);
    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(ApiUtil.MODIFY_BOX),
        headers: headers, body: jsonEncode(body));
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var body = jsonDecode(response.body);
      var data = body['message'];
      print(data);
      inspect(data);
      return data;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to modify box');
    }
  }
```

I want to add `$id` to `url((Uri.parse(ApiUtil.MODIFY_BOX))`... How can I do that correctly?

Comment: Uri.parse(ApiUtil.MODIFY_BOX + '/' + id.toString())

Comment: Great my friend . thank you for helping @Nisanth Reddy

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in chat

Comment: @NisanthReddy add an answer, before OP accepts Lucas's answer. You came with the solution first

Comment: @SilkeNL That's ok. I don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified method:

```
Future<String> modifyBox(String name, int id) async {
   SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   String token = localStorage.getString('access_token');

   //Dont need to add other parameter
   Map<String, String> headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
   };
   Map<String, dynamic> body = {
    'boxName': name,
   };

  //Here is the solution
  String apiUrl = ApiUtil.MODIFY_BOX +'/' + id.toString();

  var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(apiUrl),headers: headers, body: jsonEncode(body));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var body = jsonDecode(response.body);
        var data = body['message'];
        return data;
    } else {
       throw Exception('Failed to modify box');
    }
  }
```